# Where does the Quake Live plugin store downloaded content?

Tags: quake-live

Want to copy it to another system (*not browser*) without downloading it again...

Comment: Probably you should specify your OS and the browsers you are using.

Comment: Firefox on Windows XP. But if anyone would write a recipe for another OSes and browsers that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user data can be found depending on your OS in the following directories:

Windows 7 (probably vista as well)
X:/User/YourUserName/AppData/LocalLow/id Software/quakelive
You might have to enable the show hidden files option.

Mac OS X:
/Users/YourUserName/Library/Application Support/QuakeLive/quakelive/

Linux:
/home/YourUserName/.quakelive/

Comment: Yeah thanks. That's what i wanted.
BTW. You just need to copy this folder to another system's AppData and install browser plugin to start playing.

Comment: `x:\Documents and Settings\<USERNAME>\Application Data\id Software\quakelive` on Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run in multiple browsers without re-downloading the data.  You only need the plugin for the browser you are using, which is ~6MB download.

Comment: Yeah for sure, but I needed them on another computer. Thanks.

Comment: OK, only saw this before the edit when it said browser.  NP.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7, you can access the folder easiest by clicking the Windows Start Icon (at the bottom-left of your PC screen), and typing the following (or copy-and-pasting) into the search field:

```
%userprofile%/appdata/locallow/id software/quakelive/
```

In the AppData folder, it looks like this:

```
Local
LocalLow
Roaming
```

You can find many application folder in one of these folders.

For example, the Google Chrome folder is found in: `%AppData%/Roaming/Google/`

For future reference, the AppData folder is located in your usersname folder (where downloads and documents and pictures folders are), but it is a hidden folder.

You can turn on hidden folders to be visible by doing the following:

1. open any Windows Explorer folder window,
2. choose the `Organize` dropdown menu (in the top-right of the window),
3. choose `Folder and search options`,
4. click on the `View` tab, and
5. choose `Show hidden files, folders, and drives`.

Hope this helps!
Good luck!